# Degrees of freedom of a linear function of four independent random variables

Tags: p-value, degrees-of-freedom

This is basically a modified version of a previously unanswered question I posed [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31937/how-to-get-p-value-for-indirectly-generated-random-variables), as I'm starting to have second thoughts about my methodology.

In summary, I have four random variables:

X<sub>ideal</sub>, X<sub>nonideal</sub>, Y<sub>ideal</sub>, Y<sub>nonideal</sub>,

which I have sampled a different number of times (> 30).

I am able to get the difference between X<sub>ideal</sub> and X<sub>nonideal</sub> (denoted `X`) as well as the difference between Y<sub>ideal</sub> and Y<sub>nonideal</sub> (denoted `Y`), which I can display as mean difference and standard error:

```
     N_ideal  N_nonideal  Mean Difference  Standard Error
X    64       62          23.5             1.56
Y    71       67          27.1             1.67
```

I'm now looking to get the p-value to assess the difference between X and Y. The t-statistic if I'm not mistaken is simply

$$
t_s = (27.1 - 23.5)/\sqrt{1.56^2 + 1.67^2};
$$

I guess the question is now, how do I calculate the degrees of freedom (df)?

Edit:
I calculated the standard error with the following formula
$$
ste_{X} = \sqrt{ \sigma^2_{X_{ideal}}/N_{X_{ideal}}+\sigma^2_{X_{nonideal}}/N_{X_{nonideal}}}
$$

Edit 2: Ok, to sum this up, I have four independent random variables, I need the df of

$$
Z = (X_{i}-X_{n}) - (Y_{i}-Y_{n})
$$

Looking at the Welch–Satterthwaite equation, would my answer be:

(if $$Nt_x = N_x - 1$$)

$$
v_Z = \frac{(Var(X_{i})+Var(X_{n}) + Var(Y_{i})+ Var(Y_{n}))^2}{(Var(X_{i}))^2/Nt_{Xi}+(Var(X_{n}))^2/Nt_{Xn}+(Var(Y_{i}))^2/Nt_{Yi}+(Var(Y_{n}))^2/Nt_{Yn}} = 236
$$

or

$$
v_Z = \frac{(Var(X_{i})-Var(X_{n}) - Var(Y_{i} )+ Var(Y_{n}))^2}{(Var(X_{i}))^2/Nt_{Xi}+(Var(X_{n}))^2/Nt_{Xn}+(Var(Y_{i}))^2/Nt_{Yi}+(Var(Y_{n}))^2/Nt_{Yn}} = 16
$$

Comment: Exactly how did you compute the standard errors?

Comment: the perennial question... see edit

Comment: The edit is unclear: each SE refers to *two* sets of data, so what exactly are $s_a^2$, $N_a$, $s_b^2$, and $N_b$?  (Underlying these prompts is a concern about pooled *versus* unpooled estimates.) BTW, there are enough data here that determining a precise value for degrees of freedom will make only a tiny difference.

Comment: @whuber The standard error is of difference between ideal and non-ideal

Comment: Yes, but *how is it calculated*?  See the [Wikipedia article on pooled variance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pooled_variance) to see what the issue is.

Comment: @whuber I'm still not sure what you're referring to. X_ideal is a variable with it's own mean and std (sigma - calculated with an unbiased estimator). I have computed the random variable X = X_ideal - X_nonideal, whose properties are mean(X) = mean(X_ideal) - mean(X_nonideal), var(X) = var(X_ideal) + var(X_nonideal) and se(X) = sqrt(se(X_ideal)^2 + se(X_nonideal)^2). I have not pooled anything as of yet to resemble Wikipedia's article. Also note that the premise of pooled variance is that the true variance is assumed to remain the same which is not true between any of my RV

Comment: You have *four* variables but you provide only two standard errors. If you will not explain how you compute those SEs from your data, it will not be possible to know how to answer your question.

Comment: @whuber Rasman's approach is to treat the prepost (ideal versus nonideal) differences as fixed and to determine if there is mediation by group (X versus Y). This approach is simply a two sample T-test between the pair-differences treating the differences between ideal and non-ideal as observed values.

Comment: @AdamO I still don't see that: if what you say is true, then the *counts* for ideal vs non-ideal should match, but they don't.

Comment: @whuber I suspect you are over-thinking this. I have four independent random processes, each has its own mean, std, var and standard error (the traditional formula is s^2/N). These four random process were measured a a different number of time in an independent fashion: Xi has 64 measurements, Xn has 62 measurements (see table). I'm looking for the p-value of the random process Z = (Xi - Xn) - (Yi - Yn). I know what the t-stat is, I just need the df

Comment: Thank you--now I understand what you have done (almost, because you still haven't stated what formula you use for the SDs, but that doesn't really matter). You are asking a difficult question, because your statistic doesn't exactly have a t distribution. This appears to be a variant of the Behrens-Fisher problem and could be addressed with a Welch-Satterthwaite approximation: see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welch%27s_t_test. After you look at that, it would be understandable if you decided that determining the DF to the second decimal place (or more) might not be worth the effort :-).

Comment: @whuber I assumed he was restricting to a complete case analysis for paired observations. Thanks for bringing that to light.

Comment: @AdamO well I kindda am, and I am not trying to be a purist, but that is simply the crudest way of umming up the problem

Comment: @whuber ... which was why I didn't understand your obsession with the pooled calculations (note that I also said std was calculted using an unbiased estimator). I saw that page, as well as Welch-Satterthwaite, and all I want is a rounded value of the DF (but I do need a formula)...

Comment: Pooling changes the DF by one (and therefore could change the DF of the difference by two): that was why I was concerned.

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of ways to approach this. Because of the balanced design, you were able to take differences between various values of $X = X_i - X_n$ and $Y = Y_i - Y_n$. (subscript $n$ meaning nonideal, not sample size).

You are treating $X$ and $Y$ as independent samples and testing the hypothesis $\mu_X = \mu_Y$ with an ordinary T-test for unequal standard errors. Using this methodology consistently, you can calculate standard errors using the [Satterthwaite DFs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welch%E2%80%93Satterthwaite_equation).

However, had you had an unbalanced design, I would have advocated the regression modeling approach and a test of interaction. Using the full model:

$E[outcome | group, ideal] = \beta_0 + \beta_1 group + \beta_2 ideal + \beta_3 group*ideal$

versus the reduced model:

$E[outcome | group, ideal] = \beta_0 + \beta_1 group + \beta_2 ideal$

The benefit of doing this aside from allowing for unbalanced design is that you get explicit estimates of marginal effects, such as the group differences and the ideal versus nonideal differences.

Comment: Thank you for your response, and I saw that page, I'm just not sure I am interpreting it properly. I'm guessing the numerator is (Var(X) - Var (Y))^2 and the denominator's vi is (Ni - 1) for each of the four random variables?

Comment: Also, how do you define "balanced"?

Comment: The design would be unbalanced if some subjects did not measure their ideal or non-ideal performance. Their differences would be excluded from the final analysis with your approach, but the regression modeling approach could apply their information to estimation of group / ideal effects.

Comment: The trick to your problem is realizing that you've no longer got 4 variables, but instead have 2 variables: the differences in X and Y groups. The Ns would be the number of *differences* (e.g. w/ 50 subjects and 100 test results, you have 50 differences and hence N_i = 50 for that group)

Comment: Ok, I lost you on that last bit. In my case what is N_x and N_y ?